# Why does the following lines of code throw an IllegalStateException?

Tags: java, android, sockets

I want to connect an android app to a server with java's `ServerSocket` and `Socket` classes.
I am using the following line at the client to connect to the server:

```
var socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.21"), 59090);
```

("192.168.1.21" is my computer's ip)
Now, when I'm opening a simple java project file it is working, but when I'm trying this line in an android project and I run it through a simulator it throws the said exception and crashes.
[image: the associated stack trace]
Does anybody know why?

Comment: Please edit your question and post the complete stack trace associated with the crash.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text.

Comment: Look into `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace shows the problem is that a NetworkOnMainThreadException was thrown.

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException) for that exception says you can't do network operations on your main thread.

As for how I knew where to look: the stack trace says that the IllegalStateException was caused by an InvocationTargetException which was caused by a NetworkOnMainThreadException.

Answer (score 1):

you need to create AsyncTask and create new Socket within AsyncTask. You can't make a network call inside UI main thread.